# Quantum harmonic oscillator hamiltonian linkage to the parity operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, parity

Can you write the quantum harmonic oscillator hamiltonian
$$H = -\dfrac{\hbar^2}{2m}\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}+\dfrac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$$
in terms of the parity operator $P$?

---

**Edit broadening the scope of the question**

(not by the OP, but, instead, Cosmas Zachos.) I think the proper question here is

> "Write the parity operator in terms of the quantum SHO hamiltonian".

Comment: Do you understand how $P$ acts on the wavefunction?

Comment: Yes, but I don’t understand how I am supposed to write the hamiltonian, i.e. an operator, “in terms of the parity”.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Yes, it is a homework. Maybe I just don’t understand the question

Comment: I suspect that there is a misunderstanding of the problem, but homework-like problems are off-topic here.

Comment: @G.Smith homework like problems are *not* off topic. Please read the help center more carefully.

Comment: @DanielSank Moderator ACuriousMind’s standard sentence is “Please note that homework-like questions and check-my-work questions are generally considered off-topic here.” I regret omitting the “generally” and failing to explain to the OP when they can be on-topic.

Comment: The OP appears to have decoupled more than 3 yrs ago, so it is unlikely he adds details for clarity as the closers require. The question is naturally malformed, confusing cause & effect, but the logical arrows can be reconstructed, as I did in my answer. His teacher most likely asked a good and sophisticated question...

Comment: Voting to reopen. A perfectly clear question with good answers below.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For one thing $P^2=\hat{1}$ so its eigenvalues of $\pm 1$.  Moreover, $P$ generates discrete transformations $x\to -x$, $p\to -p$.

It is certainly not true that $H^2=\hat{1}$ or that the eigenvalues of $\hat H$ are limited to $\pm 1$.  $e^{-i Ht}$ are continuous not discrete transformations, i.e. $H$ generates continuous not discrete transformations.

It is true that $P$ commutes with $H$, meaning the eigenstates of $H$ are also eigenstates of $P$, i.e. the eigenstate of $H$ have definite parity.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly believe you "misheard" your homework problem, which, instead,  should have been something like

> "Write the parity operator in terms of the SHO hamiltonian".

The Parity operator is, of course,
$$
P= \int \!\! dx ~|-x\rangle \langle x|, 
$$
manifestly hermitean and unitary, $P^2={\mathbb I}$, so that
$$
P\hat x  P= -\hat x, \qquad P\hat p P= -\hat p.
$$

Nondimensionalize $\hbar=1$ for simplicity; and consider the ([iconic Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)) action of the operator
$$
\bbox[yellow]{\hat \Pi \equiv  e^{i\pi(\hat p^2+ \hat x ^2 -1)/2} }, \qquad \leadsto \\
\hat \Pi \hat x \hat\Pi^\dagger=\hat x+i\pi[(\hat p^2+ \hat x ^2 -1)/2,\hat x]\\   -(\pi^2/2)[(\hat p^2+ \hat x ^2 -1)/2,[(\hat p^2+ \hat x ^2 -1)/2, \hat x]]+...  \\ 
=\hat x \cos\pi + \hat p \sin\pi=-\hat x,\\
\hat \Pi \hat p \hat\Pi^\dagger =... =\hat p \cos\pi - \hat x \sin\pi=- \hat p. 
$$

You know about the integer spectrum of of the nondimensionalized, $m=1$, $\omega=1$, shifted SHO hamiltonian, $(\hat p^2+ \hat x ^2 -1)/2$ .  This oscillator hamiltonian rotates the canonical quantum variables in a rigid circle, uniformly in time: the magic of the oscillator in phase space.

For the very same reason, you should then also appreciate, by inspection, the hermiticity, $\hat \Pi=\hat \Pi^\dagger $, and unitarity $\hat \Pi \hat \Pi^\dagger ={\mathbb I}$, of $\hat \Pi$.

So $\hat \Pi$ is really a faithful representation of  $P$. To comport with your title, you might contemplate taking its logarithm, but I cannot imagine your problem willfully descended into this type of subtlety...